# Add images to a children class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've something like this :

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FooImage(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey('Foo', related_name='image')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='goo/zoo/', null=True)

class Bar(Foo):
    pass
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class FooBar(Bar):
    pass
```

Here you just have `FooBar` as child, but there'll be many other children.

I want to create a `FooBar` object with, for exemple, 5 images. And I don't understand how it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the FK is from Foo (and its children) *to* FooImage, and not the other way round, it makes no difference that you are using inheritance here: you can add the images directly to the FooBar instance as if it were a standalone one.

```
my_foo_bar = FooBar.objects.create(field=value)
my_foo_bar.images.add(my_foo_image)
# or
FooImage.objects.create(model=my_foo_bar, image=my_image)
```

Comment: Oh okay easy. But I can't have a FK to an abstract class, wright?